# HTTP Post get token response?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working with the Sinusbot API making post Requests in Java.

I make the most and get a response of 200, which is good.

However, It's also suppose to return a token for login when making the request, but I can't figure out how to get it.

Any ideas?

https://www.sinusbot.com/api/#api-General-login

Within a try catch statement

```html
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1:8087/api/v1/bot/login");
     // StringEntity params =new StringEntity("{'username': 'xx','password': 'foobar', 'botId': 'fillme'}");
      String payload = "{'username': 'test','password': 'atisbot', 'botId': '2ad5bffa-4374-4ef4-abae-77e793163577'}"; //atisbot 172b398f-f217-4bbc-8e14-9ea5f1463db7
      StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(payload,
                 ContentType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
         request.setEntity(entity);

         
         HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
         
         System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: It probably returns a JSON response; try parsing it.

Comment: That's the thing I get this back when I print response.toString();  HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8000, Date: Sun, 17 Jun 2018 23:55:50 GMT, Content-Length: 105, Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8,Content-Length: 105,Chunked: false]}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response is plain text and it probably is the token.

```
String token = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())
```